# Задержка внутри цикла в JS

Tags: javascript, анимация

Имеется цикл, в теле которого каким-то образом изменяется массив. И функция, которая отрисовывает этот массив на canvas.

Нужно чтобы в конце каждого шага цикла функция, отрисовывающая массив, вызывалась с задержкой. Пытался сделать примерно так:

```
var myArray
for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    // как-то изменяем myArray...
    // и отрисовываем на канве с задержкой
    setTimeout(drawOnCanvas(myArray), 2000)
}
```

Но дело в том, что когда вызывается setTimeout на первом шаге и ждет 2 с. цикл успевает полностью выполниться и drawOnCanvas рисует не массив после первой итерации, а массив, который получен после выполнения всего цикла. Что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Это стандартное поведение Javascript. Если не ошибаюсь то это связано с его работой только в одном потоке, также у вас ошибка при передачи первого параметра в функцию `setTimeout`, а именно вы передаете туда результат функции, а не её саму или ссылку на неё.

Как решение можно воспользоваться методом [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) объекта `Function`

Получится что-то вроде,

```
var myArray
for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    setTimeout(drawOnCanvas.bind(this, myArray), 2000);
}
```

Внимание! Первый параметр метода `bind` будет контекстом функции.